# Python does not overwrite int with float

Tags: python, floating-point, division

I got some trouble here with Python. Using Python 2.X and know it has some difficulties with division, that's why I added `from __future__ import division` and it works fine so far. But I noticed that when I want to overwrite an int with a float in this project it doesn't work, I tested it in a smaller project but there it worked fine.

Has anyone a clue what's wrong here?

```
A = [
  [3, 3, 3],
  [1, 1, 2],
  [1, 0, 3]
]
b = [0, 0, 3]     

def gauss_elim(A,b):
    print A[0], b[0]
    print A[1], b[1]
    print A[2], b[2]    
    n = len(A)
    temp = []
    temp_b = []
    MAX = 0
    te = [0,0,0]

    for i in range(0,n-1):
        k=i
        for a in range(i,n-1):               
            ### Pivotsearch Start ###               
            if math.fabs(A[a][i]) < math.fabs(A[a+1][i]):
                MAX = (a+1)
                temp = A[i]
                A[i] = A[MAX]
                A[MAX] = temp

                temp_b = b[i]
                b[i] =b[MAX]
                b[MAX]=temp_b                   
            ### Pivotsearch End ###               
        for j in range(i+1, n):                 
            if A[j][i] == 0:                
               continue

            A[j][i] = A[j][i] - ( A[j][i] /  A[i][i]  ) *  A[i][i]
            b[j] = ( b[j] - (A[j][i])/(A[i][i]) ) #<<<< DOES NOT OVERWRITE
            k = k + 1

    print 'done:'        
    print A[0], b[0]
    print A[1], b[1]
    print A[2], b[2]

gauss_elim(A,b)
```

Comment: `float` is wider (bigger) than `int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the line

```
b[j] = ( b[j] - (A[j][i])/(A[i][i]) )
```

doesn't change `b[j]` is that at that point in the code, `(A[j][i])` is 0. Try printing it out and you'll see.

Look at the line before:

```
A[j][i] = A[j][i] - ( A[j][i] /  A[i][i]  ) *  A[i][i]
```

You can cancel out the `A[i][i]` to get:

```
A[j][i] = A[j][i] - A[j][i]
A[j][i] = 0
```

You might have been confused because this same result occurs in different ways whether or not `from __future__ import division` has been used. If `from __future__ import division` has been included, `A[j][i]` will always be 0. If it hasn't been included, `A[j][i]` won't be 0- but `(A[j][i])/(A[i][i])`, in the following line, *will*.

Comment: @ShuftY Sure thing. Don't forget that you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to it.